# How to display line items in twos?

Tags: html, css

I have this site:

[link](http://dgprint.dg-site.com/)

At the bottom you will find the footer which has 7 items (printing, textile, photo, advertising, gastronomy, about us, contact).

Currently all these elements are in line this shape

```
Printing-Textile-Photo-Advertising-Gastronomy-About US-Contact
```

I want to do so

```
Printing-Textile
Photo-Advertising
Gastronomy-About US
Contact
```

**CODE HTML**

```
<div class="site-info container">
    <div class="footer-blocks">
          //some code HTML
    </div>
    <div class="footer-blocks">
          //some code HTML
    </div>
    <div class="footer-blocks">
          //some code HTML
    </div>
    <div class="footer-blocks">
         //some code HTML
    </div>
    <div class="footer-blocks">
         //some code HTML
    </div>
    <div class="footer-blocks">
         //some code HTML
    </div>
    <div class="footer-blocks">
         //some code HTML
    </div>
</div>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
.footer-blocks{
  float:left;
  width:12%;
  color:#fff;
  margin-right:2%;
  text-align:left;
}
.footer-blocks:last-child{
  margin-right:0;
}
```

I tried to modify the CSS code and got it form

```
<div class="site-info container">
        <div class="footer-blocks" style="float:left">
              //some code HTML
        </div>
        <div class="footer-blocks" style="float:left">
              //some code HTML
        </div>
        <div class="footer-blocks" style="float:left">
              //some code HTML
        </div>
        <div class="footer-blocks">
             //some code HTML
        </div>
        <div class="footer-blocks">
             //some code HTML
        </div>
        <div class="footer-blocks">
             //some code HTML
        </div>
        <div class="footer-blocks">
             //some code HTML
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CODE CSS NEW:**

```
.footer-blocks{
  width:12%;
  color:#fff;
  margin-right:2%;
  text-align:left;
}
```

I know it is not good what we tried but I do not figure out how I could arrange them as they wish.

Probably something simple but I do not know how to fix it.
Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Apply a fixed with to the container. that will fix it.

Comment: `width: 50%; margin: 0; float: left` ? and limit the parent width to 320 for example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the width to 48% for the blocks and min-height will give it equal area in vertical direction. If you need to limit the spacing between the columns, set a fixed width for the parent element.

```css
.site-info.container {
  width: 500px; /* Add */
}
.footer-blocks {
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2%;
  min-height: 330px; /* Add */
  text-align: left;
  width: 48%; /* Add */
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add

```
<div style="clear: both;">
```

after each 2 blocks

and change:

```
.footer-blocks{
  float:left;
  width:12%;
  color:#fff;
  margin-right:2%;
  text-align:left;
}
```

to:

```
.footer-blocks{
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using bootstrap, you can split every two columns into different rows.
Here's some code to get you started

```
<div class="site-info container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="footer-blocks">
                 -- Printing Stuff
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="footer-blocks">
                 -- Textile Stuff
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="footer-blocks">
                 -- Photo Stuff
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="footer-blocks">
                 -- Advertising Stuff
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    -- ETC.
</div>
```

Also, there's no need to add the style float:left for your inline css since it's already in the class.

You should check out the bootstrap documentation for more help:
[Grid Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)